# Calculating age from one input and updating another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I must be missing something simple here, but I would love some help.

First, the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="dob" />
<input id="age" type="text" name="age" />
```

And the Javascript

```
$('input[name=dob]').change(getAge);
$('input[name=age]').change(getAge);
function getAge() {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date($('input[name=dob]').val());
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    $('#age').val(age);
 };
```

This is not working for me. When I input a date in the "dob" field, the "age" field returns NaN.

Comment: I'm sorry that it wasn't clear.  This is not working for me.  When I input a date in the "dob" field, the "age" field returns NaN. I'll update my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're not getting the correct age (or any numerical return at all).  A few suggestions:

1. You have a single quote hanging off the end of the code block. 
   Remove it since it might be causing an uncaught error.
2. It doesn't seem that you are enforcing or verifying any formatting of the 'dob' input.  The Date object only takes specific types of inputs.  Find out which you would like and then enforce it (with a message to the user and a check before using it).
3. On the second part of your 'if' statement, use parentheses to make sure it's checking what you want.  I believe that the way you have it written causes this check: `( (m === 0) && today.getDate() ) < birthDate.getDate()`.  Try this: `(m === 0) && ( today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate() )`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the insights.  The single quote was an anomaly from posting my code.  It's not in my actual code.  I've updated my original post. You are correct that I'm not enforcing a date format (yet).  I've been inputting the date (for testing) as YYYYMMDD. Is that incorrect? I made the change to the if statement, but the result is the same, NaN.

Comment: I answered my own question here.  I was using MySQL style of date input, and that is incorrect.  I'm marking your answer as correct because it led me to the fix.  Thank you! For anyone who might be curious, the correct default input is MM/DD/YYYY.